# Pass through unix shell pipe

Tags: bash, shell

What is the UNIX shell program that just returns input?

For example

```
> echo "test" | $pass
> test # output
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `cat`.

When `cat` is used without any command line arguments. It just copies the standard input to standard output.

Comment: hmmm... I guess it is obvious - could not figure out though

Comment: Also, to make clear that you want cat specifically to read stdin, there's `cat -`

Answer (score 1):

`cat`

Answer (score 1):

`cat` .

#### Note

There's also `tac` which performs the reverse of `cat`.

Comment: To be clear, `tac` prints the lines in reverse order.